# Set of functions defined up to a sign

Tags: general-topology, functions, vector-spaces, differential-topology, quotient-spaces

Let $C^{\infty}(I)$ denote the vector space of smooth functions from an interval $I$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Let $\sim$ be the following equivalence relation on $C^{\infty}(I)$:
$$ f \sim g \Leftrightarrow f = -g\,.$$

Question: is the quotient $C^{\infty}(I)/{\sim}$ a vector space? What is its dimension?

Comment: Is this an equivalence relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relation is not an equivalence relation, as $f \sim f$ is not true for $f \not \equiv 0$. If you amend your definition to

$$ f \sim g \iff f=g \text { or } f=-g$$

then your construct is not a vector space, as addition is not preserved under the quotient. Take any $f \in C^\infty (I)$ that is not identical to the zero function. We have $f \sim f$ and $f \sim -f$, but not $2f=f+f \sim f+ (-f) = 0$.